# How to switch id of ul after click on li element?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to dynamically change id of ul element after click on li element. Then I pass this id to str variable as a string. For an example when I click on Driver 2 id of ul changes for "?driver_id=2",

I've got something like this:

```
<ul class="drivers" id="">
     <li><a href="" id="?driver_id=1">Driver 1</a></li>
     <li><a href="" id="?driver_id=2">Driver 2</a></li>
     <li><a href="" id="?driver_id=3">Driver 3</a></li>
 </ul>
```

and jquery:

```
var str=$('ul.drivers').attr('id');
```

Comment: I would strongly recommend you don't do this. `id` attributes are not meant to be transient. If you want to dynamically identify element, change their classes instead

Comment: Building on what @Rory said, `id`s are also supposed to be unique - what you're proposing would end up with a duplicated `id`.

Comment: Agreed with @RoryMcCrossan. But still if you want to know, how to do it, try this `$('ul.drivers').attr('id', 'my_new_id');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the `id` attribute isn't a great idea because they must be unique, and shouldn't be changing throughout the DOM.

Instead, the `data` attribute seems like a better use.  You can set the attribute, and access its value using something like this:

**HTML**

```
<ul class="drivers" id="list">
   <li><a href="#" data-driver="?driver_id=1">Driver 1</a></li>
   <li><a href="#" data-driver="?driver_id=2">Driver 2</a></li>
   <li><a href="#" data-driver="?driver_id=3">Driver 3</a></li>
</ul>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#list li a').on('click',function() {
    var str = $(this).data('driver');
    console.log(str);
  })
})
```

Here it is in a JS Fiddle example:  https://jsfiddle.net/igor_9000/wh3v1wsk/

Hope that helps!

Comment: You helped me a lot! I've got one more question. When i pass data from ul list to this php script it response me some json and then my JS framework draws chart. It works perfectly. But this JS script has some interval function which should update chart. It does'nt work. I've got some trouble with passing str variable to this function. Error says that str is undefined. Here is code of index.php http://pastebin.com/Zzy0YEPi

Comment: @pkosmicki it would be good to start a new question for that.  If you do open a new question, please provide a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  The pastbin is not particularly helpful because it doesn't reproduce the issue.  Also, if the answers here have been useful please upvote and choose one as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

as some of the comments mentioned, this is not a good idea. The `id` attribute is supposed to be unique, so by setting the id of the `ul` to the id of one of the `li`s, youre creating two ids on your page, which will mask one of them if you try searching for it again.

but if you're trying to change attributes with jquery, use the second argument of `attr` to set the attrib

```
$('ul.drivers').attr('id', value)
```

if you want to use class instead of id, use jquerys `addClass` method.

```
$('ul.drivers').addClass(value)
```

though i would recommend using a custom data attribute

```
$('ul.drivers').data('some-name', value) //=> set value
$('ul.drivers').data('some-name') //=> get value
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of changing the id, create a data attribute, like this:

```
<ul class="drivers" id="driverlist-1" data-active-driver-id="">
  <li><a href="" id="?driver_id=1">Driver 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="" id="?driver_id=2">Driver 2</a></li>
  <li><a href="" id="?driver_id=3">Driver 3</a></li>
</ul>

<ul class="drivers" id="driverlist-2" data-active-driver-id="">
  <li><a href="" id="?driver_id=4>Driver 4</a></li>
  <li><a href="" id="?driver_id=5">Driver 5</a></li>
  <li><a href="" id="?driver_id=6">Driver 6</a></li>
</ul>
```

**Data Attributes** are meant to store *data* you need to control for any reason. Please, refer to [this link](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_data.asp).

Then you change it like this, accessing your ul with its id, because think, if you had two uls each one with its own **drivers**, you'd guarantee the proper one would be changed:

```
$('#driverlist-1').data('active-driver-id', value); // setting some value to it
var str = $('#driverlist-1').data('active-driver-id'); // getting stored value
```

where `value` is the id of the clicked `li`. I'd recommend following this even if you don't have two lists at all, just to keep good practices.